# Using JQuery to add selected items from one combobox to another

Tags: jquery, appendto

I'm trying to find the best way to add selected items from one combobox to another.  The trick is I only want to add items to the destination list that don't already exist.  Currently the process I use is rather ugly and does not work as I would expect.

```
$('#addSelectedButton').click(function() {
    var previousOption;
    $('#sourceList option:selected').appendTo('#destinationList');
    $('select[name=destinationList] option').each(function () {
        if (this.text == previousOption) $(this).remove();
        previousOption = this.text;
    });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the ***appendTo*** method acts as more of a move rather than an add.  Then there's the problem of removing the duplicates, which works in this this example, but I can't help but think there's a better way.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: can you add html snippet as well.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to append one jQuery element already in the DOM to another element?](/q/6364633/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `clone()` and `grep()` you can achieve this easily. First *clone* the options that are selected from the source and then using *grep* you can filter out the items that are already in the destination list.

```
$('#addSelectedButton').click(function() {
    // select this once into a variable to minimize re-selecting
    var $destinationList = $('#destinationList');

    // clone all selected items
    var $items = $.grep($('#sourceList option:selected').clone(), function(v){
        // if the item does not exist return true which includes it in the new array
        return $destinationList.find("option[value='" + $(v).val() + "']").length == 0;

    });

    // append the collection to the destination list
    $destinationList.append($items);
});
```

---

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/4GK9A/

---

**[clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)**

> Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

**[grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)**

> Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.

Comment: Nice use of grep! Forgot about that one.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to use "clone" in conjunction with append:

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 1):

You could use clone() like this:

```
$('#addSelectedButton').click(function() {
    var previousOption;
    var clone =  $('#sourceList option:selected').clone();
    clone.appendTo('#destinationList');
    $('select[name=destinationList] option').each(function () {
        if (this.text == previousOption) $(this).remove();
        previousOption = this.text;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just search the destination list for the containing value. http://jsfiddle.net/EHqem/

```
$('#addSelectedButton').click(function() {
    $('#sourceList option:selected').each(function(i, el) {
        if ($('#destinationList option[value='+$(el).val()+']').length === 0) {
           $('#destinationList').append($(el).clone());
        }
    });
});
```