# MySQL to List/select box but with a twist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm looking to show available jobs from my database to a listbox. This part has been done. When the user clicks on a job title it will display the related information on all the columns of that row selected. This is also done.

The main step is to allow the user to choose the jobs they want and "save" them for later use. I have implemented 2 list/select boxes with 2 buttons to move the selected job back and forth.

What I need help with is understanding what the best method to do this. Either by pulling the data into an array then displaying on the list and how would I copy the information to the chosen select box. If it is possible could you show me an example?

First select box:

```
<select id="val" size="6" name="val" onChange="tell();" style="float:left; width:200px">

<?php
 while( $info = mysql_fetch_array ($data))
 {

echo "<option data-id='$info[0]' data-county='$info[2]' data-eng='$info[3]' 
data-schdate='$info[4]' data-company='$info[5]' data-contact='$info[6]' 
data-visitno='$info[7]' data-systype='$info[8]' data-address='$info[9]'>$info[5]
</option>"; 

 }
 ?>

</select>
```

Tell Function:

```
function tell()
{
var JobID = $('select#val option:selected').data("id");
var County = $('select#val option:selected').data("county");
var Engineer = $('select#val option:selected').data("eng");
var SchDate = $('select#val option:selected').data("schdate");
var Company = $('select#val option:selected').data("company");
var contactNo = $('select#val option:selected').data("contact");
var VisitNo = $('select#val option:selected').data("visitno");
var SysType = $('select#val option:selected').data("systype");
var Address = $('select#val option:selected').data("address");

$("#display").html("<b>Job ID: </b>" + JobID + "<br>" + "<b>County: </b>" + County 
+ "<br>" + "<b>Engineer: </b>" + Engineer + "<br>" + "<b>Scheduled Date: </b>" + 
SchDate + "<br>" + "<b>Company: </b>" + Company + "<br>" + "<b>Contact number </b>" +
contactNo + "<br>" + "<b>Visit Number: </b>" + VisitNo + "<br>" + "<b>System Type: </b>"
+ SysType + "<br>" + "<b>Address: </b>" + Address);
}
```

Example of what is going on:
http://s27.postimg.org/h84a45dtf/problem.jpg

Comment: Your question isn't clear pal!

Comment: Sorry, I need a way to show other information from the database that matches the selection on the list. I have that but its showing it directly from the while loop. I need to put it into an array.. i think.?

Comment: Madi, post has been editted.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle if the information that I have provided is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Its close. I should maybe explain what happens when you click on an option. when the user clicks on an option the data below, found @ http://s27.postimg.org/h84a45dtf/problem.jpg will change depending on the selection. The information displayed is from mysql database. Once the user selects the jobs they want, by clicking on the jobs then moving them across to the other select box. i then need to store the selected jobs into an array on the  client side to then be stored within local storage. How would i go about this?

Comment: Ps. i got the whole array to local storage sorted. just need a method to store the selected jobs to an array =)

Comment: I need all the information such as JobID, County, etc to be stored in the array. I know I'm rubbish at explaining this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring where the selected items are to be moved to another combo-box, someone has already asked the question.

here is the link: [Using JQuery to add selected items from one combobox to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570629/using-jquery-to-add-selected-items-from-one-combobox-to-another)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Would this copy my data attrs?

Comment: That means your question is still not clear buddy. What is that you want?